# r - Knowing which data.table join to use prior to join

Tags: r, data.table

**Question**

Is it possible to know which is the most efficient `data.table` 'join' to use before performing the join?

The goal of this is to join two tables, `dt1` and `dt2`, on a common key `alpha`, where `dt1$beta <= dt2$beta`. Two example tables:

```
# dt1                       dt2
#        id alpha beta          alpha beta
#  1:    35   A   284       1:      A  478
#  2:    74   A   916       2:      A 1034
#  ---                      --- 
# 9999:  9967 Z   483       9999:   Z  303
# 10000: 9988 Z   473       10000:  Z 1411
```

It may be the case that `non-equi` joins, when implemented, will solve this, but for now I'm wonding if there is a way of telling from the size of the two tables the best method to use.

In the examples the 'quickest' method changes depending on the size of the tables. They are also representative of my actual data, which will change regularly and so I was looking to write a function that uses the 'best' join.

**Examples**

Here I've set up some functions to create data, perform a couple of joins and run a benchmark. The benchmarks are run on three different sized tables

```
library(data.table)
library(microbenchmark)

## Function to create data.tables
fun_create_data <- function(s1, s2){
  set.seed(123)   ## keep consistency
  dt1 <- data.table(id = seq(1:s1),
                    alpha = sample(LETTERS, size=s1, replace=T),
                    beta = sample(1:1440, size=s1, replace=T))

  dt2 <- data.table(alpha = sample(LETTERS, size=s2, replace=T),
                    beta = sample(1:1440, size=s2, replace=T))

  setkey(dt1, alpha)
  setkey(dt2, alpha)

  return(lst = list(dt1, dt2))
}
```

The joins I'm using are

```
## inner join, allow.cartesian = TRUE,
## then filtering out results after the join
fun_join_cartesian <- function(dt1, dt2){

  dt1[ dt2, nomatch=0, allow.cartesian=TRUE][beta <= i.beta]

}

## join using i.col (specifying criteria for each i.)
fun_join_eachi <- function(dt1, dt2){

  dt1[ dt2, {
              idx = beta <= i.beta
              .(id = id[idx],
               beta = beta[idx],
              i.beta = i.beta)
            },
            by=.EACHI
      ][!is.na(id)]

}
```

benchmark function

```
fun_mb <- function(dt1, dt2){
  microbenchmark(
    fun_join_cartesian(dt1, dt2),
    fun_join_eachi(dt1, dt2),
    times=10
  )
}
```

The fisrt example has the cartesian join performing best

```
s1 <- 1000
s2 <- s1 
lst <- fun_create_data(s1, s2)
dt1 <- lst[[1]]
dt2 <- lst[[2]]

fun_mb(dt1, dt2)
# Unit: milliseconds
#                         expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
# fun_join_cartesian(dt1, dt2) 1.727606 1.741692 1.785893 1.770675 1.778107 1.986325    10
#     fun_join_eachi(dt1, dt2) 3.490216 3.518185 3.593305 3.559949 3.662209 3.826939    10
```

The second exmaple also has the cartesian join performing best

```
s1 <- 1000
s2 <- s1 * 5
lst <- fun_create_data(s1, s2)
dt1 <- lst[[1]]
dt2 <- lst[[2]]

fun_mb(dt1, dt2)
# Unit: milliseconds
#                         expr       min       lq      mean    median       uq      max neval
# fun_join_cartesian(dt1, dt2)  5.690791  5.70429  6.433174  5.923583  6.19849 10.84091    10
#     fun_join_eachi(dt1, dt2) 12.153050 12.47688 13.469481 12.711631 13.46108 18.71149    10
```

Whereas the third example has the `eachi` join performing best

```
s1 <- 10000
s2 <- s1
lst <- fun_create_data(s1, s2)
dt1 <- lst[[1]]
dt2 <- lst[[2]]

fun_mb(dt1, dt2)
# Unit: milliseconds
#                         expr       min        lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
# fun_join_cartesian(dt1, dt2) 170.16523 171.33960 185.9685 173.3784 175.3022 299.5541    10
#     fun_join_eachi(dt1, dt2)  88.17374  95.48863 138.8535 155.7180 161.2675 162.1637    10
```

Comment: Did you try to use `foverlaps`? It address some of non-equi joins. I believe the answer on your question would heavily depends on the data, so you better benchmark your real data.

Comment: Depends what you're doing afterwards as well. I usually find that if I want to take a Cartesian join on big tables, I'm thinking about the problem wrong. Also, you do realize that those functions give different results, right?

Comment: @Frank - thanks - I forgot to strip out the `NA`s. Fixed now.

Comment: My input data will be changing regularly, and so when writing my 'join' function I was benchmarking my real data and would get the results shown here. And hence the inspiration for this question